# Finding a tighter bound for weighted sum of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence, bounds, weights

Here is the setup of my problem:

Let $X_k$ be a sequence of independent random variables in $\mathbb{R}$ with $E(X_n) = 0$ and Var($X_n$)<$\infty$ for all $n$. Let $\{a_k\}$ and $\{A_k\}$ denote positive random variables such that almost surely $A_k$ is monotonically increasing to $\infty$ and that $A_k/a_k \rightarrow \infty$. The quantity that we are interested in is the weighted sum $A_n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k X_k $. I am interested in finding a bound on
$$
P\left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k X_k}{A_n} > t\right) - (1)
$$
I found this paper by R.L. Taylor and C.A. Calhoun titled "On the almost sure convergence of randomly weighted sums of random elements". (http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2243672.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A6a964101e88747a63c3ee8740a3a1b16). They show that under some growth conditions on the random weights and moment condition on the random variables, we get almost sure convergence of this weighted sum.

Now I know that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability, so I should be able to find an upper bound for (1) such that the bound converges to 0 as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I have tried a couple of things also using martingale properties but haven't been able to get to a tight enough bound which would result in convergence in probability.

Any help, references or comments on this are much appreciated!

Comment: Some of your assumptions are meaningless, because you haven't been specific about $\operatorname{Var}(X_k)$. Due to that, you could just as well replace the $X_k$ by $\lambda_k X_k$ and $\alpha_k$ by $\alpha_k/\lambda_k$ for literally any sequence $(\lambda_k)$ of positive numbers.  Consequently, you haven't really provided any effective conditions on $A_k$, either, making it difficult to see how you could achieve anything.